# Удалить конкретные теги

Tags: javascript, jquery

В `div contenteditable` при наборе текста после первого слова ставится 1 `<br>` (стандартный) и 1 `<br>` которым я фиксил один баг. Вопрос как можно заменить эти 2 `<br><br>` на Один.

Пробовал в 
`$(div).on('keyup', function(){
    $(this).html( $(this).html().replace('<br><br>', '<br>') )
})`

Тут огромный косяк в том что эта ф-ия запускается при каждом нажатии клавиши и перезаписывает весь `HTML` и к тому же курсор ставится не в конец текста, а в начало `div`